# NSScanner’s scanString:intoString doesn’t seem to work

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
NSString *markdown = @"This is the *Markdown* syntax.";
NSScanner *aScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:markdown];

if ([aScanner scanString:@"*" intoString:nil] == YES) {
    NSLog(@"YES");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"NO");
}
```

Output:

```
NO
```

Why is my output the way it is? Shouldn’t it be `YES` since the Markdown string has an asterisk? And if it was to work would I get `YES` twice since I have two asterisk in the Markdown string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the scanner is starting at the start of the string, and you're saying that the next substring should be `@"*"`, but the string you gave it starts with `@"T"`.  Maybe you want `-scanUpToString:intoString:` instead?

Comment: Thanks. The method name isn’t very intuitive.